# Body tag is used twice in my code. How to fix this error so my code can pass validation?

Tags: html, validation

This is what I'm trying to do with my site:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader5

Unfortunately, that example assumes that I want the entire page to display a CSS loader, but my page is divided into sections, and I only want a portion of the page to display the CSS loader. The original example uses the body tag. But I can't use the body tag twice in my code or it won't pass validation. How can I fix my code so that it validates and the CSS loader still functions the way I want it to?

Please keep in mind that I am only familiar with HTML and CSS. I do not know anything about JavaScript. The little bit of JavaScript I have in my site has been copied and pasted from other sources.

The issue is with:

```
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
```

So I'm thinking that if I can change "body" to something else, then I should be good. But I don't know what I should change it to. Or how to connect the new word to the content that I want it to affect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <!-- head section begins here -->

           <!-- head section ends here -->
       </head>
       <body>
          <!-- body section begins here -->
       <div class="wrapper">

       <div class="section">
       <div class="largecontent">

       <body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
           <div id="loader"></div>
           <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">  

           <!-- www.123formbuilder.com script begins here -->
           <script type="text/javascript" defer 
           src="https://www.123formbuilder.com/embed/4923120.js"
           data-role="form" data-default-width="650px"></script>
           <!-- www.123formbuilder.com script ends here -->          

           <script>
           var myVar;
           function myFunction() {myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);}
           function showPage() 
           {document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";                                 
           document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";}
           </script>
           </div>
       </div>
       </div>

       </div>
        <!-- body section ends here -->
       </body>
   </html>
```

1) Error: Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open.

From line 130, column 21; to line 130, column 66

```
    <body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">↩
```

2) Fatal Error: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

From line 130, column 21; to line 130, column 66

```
    <body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">↩
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you can use `document.onload = function ...` and put your function in that, it will trigger after the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body onload="myFunction()">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="largecontent">
           <div  style="margin:0;">
             <div id="loader"></div>
             <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://www.123formbuilder.com/embed/4923120.js" data-role="form" data-default-width="650px"></script>
   <script>
     var myVar;
     function myFunction() {myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);}
     function showPage(){
       document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";                                 
       document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
     }
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```